# How to return a collection based on the inputs (generic)

Tags: c#, .net

beginner: 
want to write a method to return a generic collection as:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ABC( string x){

if( x== "1")
{ Collection<A> needs to be returned}

if(x=="2")
{ Collection<B> needs to be returned}
..
so on
}
```

Questions: 
- based on "X" passed to the method different types of collections are initialized and need to be returned? how can i do that? 
- is this the correct approach?
- any links to get more details on generic usages?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the type parameter (here T) must be known at compile time. Which means it can't change while running. What you could do is make it `IEnumerable<Object>`. Since every other type has Object as a base type, I'm pretty sure you could return an IEnumerable of anything at that point. Though you may need to cast in/out of Object on the way.

Answer (score 0):

no need to pass string to identify the type of class .just call with the following generic method ,it will intialize the List of that T type.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the initialize generic list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        public IList<T> GetInitializeGenericList<T>() where T : class
        {
            Type t = typeof(List<>);
            Type typeArgs =typeof(T);
            Type type = t.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            // Create the List according to Type T
            dynamic reportBlockEntityCollection = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            // If you want to pull the data into initialized list you can fill the data
            //dynamic entityObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeArgs);

            //reportBlockEntityCollection.Add(entityObject);

            return reportBlockEntityCollection;
        }
```

Comment: Why not just use `return new List<T>();` instead of using activator if you're going to use generics? (Maybe I'm just missing something.)

Comment: yeah if you want to just initialize the list of T you can  return the new List<T>().but if you need to add some data into it then it fails in that scenario. You cannot create an instance of using generic.

Comment: Sure you could. Take in an instance (or collection) of `T` and use either `.Add()` or `AddRange()` on your "newed up" collection.